# How do I prevent elements from rearranging when resizing the window?

Tags: html, css

I've tried setting the position as relative and using min-width but I can't seem to get the bracketed elements on the left to stay together. All I want it to do is stay completely still as the site is narrow and simple anyway. Is there anyway that I can make all of the elements stay exactly where they are?

Here's my site: https://pilotwhale.net/

CSS : https://pilotwhale.net/jumbotron-narrow.css

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed`.

This would fix the item and it will not rearrange itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add `float: left` on each on your col-lg-* classes, even on mobile width, otherwise the div will take all available width and get stacked on top of each other. It shoud work with a `display: inline-block`, also.

Also avoid using `<br>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried adding float:left to all the columns, to the brackets, to the brackets and the columns, to everything and the same issue still arises. What alternative is there to using <br>? If I take them out then the brackets go all over the place. I'm still really new to coding so apologies for being a bit of a dumbass aha.

Comment: element with a display: inline will take the width of their content. Elements with a display: block; takes the width of the parent minus padding. Element width display: inline-block; takes the width of the content plus padding. So you could avoid the <br> by using a display: bloc; and having the elements on the same line by using a display: inline-block. Using float:; removes elements from the float and gives them the width of their content. But you should rewrite your question and explain exactly what your want to do, right now it's unclear.